# Socket.io - How to comment on post based on post id?

Tags: php, jquery, socket.io, laravel-5

Im using Laravel 5.0 and I have a view in which i have multiple posts being displayed. There is a model relationship between my Post.php, Comment.php and my User.php

home.blade.php view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>
<p>{{ $post->description }}</p>
<div id="comments">
    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
    <h3>{{ $comment->user->username }}</h3>
    <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
    <hr>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

Using socket.io v1.3.5, how would I specify comments to each post. For example, I have a post with ID of 1 and another post with ID of 2. What must I do so that a comment made in Post 1 stays in Post 1 and a comment made in Post 2 stays in Post 2. Currently, a comment made in Post 1 will appear in the Post 2 comments section and vice versa.

PostController.php

```
 $data = [
        'event' => 'UserComment',
        'data'  => [
            'username' => Auth::user()->getUsername(),
            'comment'  => Request::input('comment'),
            'post_id'   => $id
        ]
    ];

    Redis::publish('user-comment', json_encode($data));
```

server.js

```
var server = require('http').Server();

var io     = require('socket.io')(server);

var Redis  = require('ioredis');

var redis  = new Redis();

var usernames = {};



redis.subscribe('user-comment');

redis.on('message', function(channel, message){

message = JSON.parse(message);

var room = message.data.post_id;

console.log(room);

// io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);

});

server.listen(3000);
```

home.blade.php - javascript

```
socket.on('user-comment:UserComment', function(data){
        $('#home_chat_content_div_body').append($('<h4>').text(data.username).css('color', '#00c5cd'));
        $('#home_chat_content_div_body').append($('<p>').text(data.comment));
        $('#home_chat_content_div_body').append($('<hr>'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple choices.  But, basically you want to emit your comment from PHP to SocketIO.  Essentially, PHP will function as a client of SocketIO and emit the message.  Where ever the insert in your code for the comment happens you want to emit the event to SocketIO using one of the approaches below:

You can use ElephantIO:

```
use ElephantIO\Client as Elephant;

$elephant = new Elephant('http://localhost:8000', 'socket.io', 1, false, true, true);

$elephant->init();
$elephant->send(
    ElephantIOClient::TYPE_EVENT,
    null,
    null,
    json_encode(array('name' => 'foo', 'args' => 'bar'))
);
$elephant->close();

echo 'tryin to send `bar` to the event `foo`';
```

Source: http://elephant.io/#usage

Or, if you have Redis in the background, you could use the SocketIO Redis PHP emitter:

```
$redis = new \Redis(); // Using the Redis extension provided client
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', '6379');
$emitter = new SocketIO\Emitter($redis);
$emitter->emit('chat message', 'payload str');
```

Source: https://github.com/rase-/socket.io-php-emitter

Also, you would remove this code from your index.js since it would no longer be needed:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
});
```

And... the latest version of SocketIO is 1.3.7.  Definitely upgrade if possible.

---

Example way to use rooms for SocketIO:

```
$redis = new \Redis(); // Using the Redis extension provided client
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', '6379');
$emitter = new SocketIO\Emitter($redis);
$emitter->in('post:123'); // send this event only to clients who are in this room for 'new comment'
$emitter->emit('new comment', $dataArray);
```

Then in your client:

```
socket.emit('subscribe-post', 'post:123'); // subscribe to events in the post:123 room
socket.on('new comment', function(data){
    console.log( data );
});
```

Then in node:

```
socket.on('subscribe-post', function(room) {
    socket.join(room); // join the post:123 room
});
```

Comment: so there really is no way to do this purely with socket.io and express?

Comment: you could do the insert from node instead of php then emit that way.. although I don't think that'd be a great idea.

Comment: because of possible injection vulnerability?

Comment: No because now you're doing inserts from Node instead of PHP (weird maintenance / exception for how you're storing data)  and it'd be a strange way to workaround using the methods I suggested.  Do you fully understand my suggestions? You just add some lines below where ever you're doing $comment->save(); in your PHP.  Are you able to modify the PHP at all?

Comment: yes your advice is both helpful and appreciated. My only issue is that for redis, i'll have to look into vps hosting for the application since this will eventually be pushed into a production environment and vps hosting doesnt really fall under my budget. Ive never heard of elephant.io but it sounds like its just what i need

Comment: I went ahead and used redis to publish an event where the node.js server is set to listen to and then forward the data to socket.io where it can be reflected on the client-side. The redis event im publishing was written in one of my Laravel controllers so that way Im easily able to pass the post-id, username, and the comment itself. Doing a console.log on server.js shows that the node server is successfully receiving the data. Do you happen to know what the server.js code would look like to specify commenting only on the post with the post-id that was passed through? I am so lost after here.

Comment: just woke up but what I think you're asking is: you basically want to subscribe to events only for a specific post instead of having a comment event being triggered for all events?  In your event you could do (pseudo-code): emit('post:123', $comment) and in your JS on the client: socketio.on('post:123', callback) -- alternatively & better, you could definite a room id... so in the Redis emitter you can do something like this: $emitter->in($roomId)->emit($type, $data);.. I need to get ready for work but hopefully that gives you an idea (you'll need to tweak your index.js/and client code too)

Comment: I can edit my post with a more complete example a little later today although you might be able to find what you are looking for by googling I think... cheers

Comment: If you are able to edit your post when you have some free time, i think itd be a great contribution to the stack community. I feel others have ran into the same problem and seeing this question would provide a strong reference for them, i believe. In the meantime yes, i will try google.

Comment: Edited my post.. take a look

Comment: so im actually doing something a little similar. this is what i have so far

Comment: it's better and maybe less confusing to use the redis adapter for socketio, checkout this post I made here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34220691/5207687

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97805/discussion-between-arvin-flores-and-clayton).