# Socket.io server making massive connections

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I had been running a simple (albeit memory-hungry) socket.io + redis node app to facilitate live notifications (see [Node.js + Socket.io + Redis app via PM2 with large memory footprint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33085303/1001675)), and after updating to most recent node, socket.io, redis, etc, I noticed the app growing in memory like crazy.

I've reduced the app down to this for debugging:

```
var server  = require('http').createServer(),
    io  = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8890);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(`Connection: ${socket.id} Remote: ${socket.client.conn.remoteAddress} Total: ${io.engine.clientsCount}`);
});
```

And when I run `node server.js` on a server that has about 100 users calling `socket = io('http://url-of-nodeapp/)`, it shows massive numbers of connections and memory just keeps growing and growing. The site is mostly AJAX, so the users should only be opening socket sessions every few minutes or so (some pages do complete refreshes). In other words: it should be pretty quiet.

[image: socket madness]

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Or ways to diagnose how so many sessions are being initiated?

Comment: I've seen this issue when you have a mismatched version of socket.io on client and server starting with the most recent version of socket.io 2.x.  The client connects, the connection fails so it immediately tries again, virtually forever.  And, because of the way socket.io works with an initial polling, it takes the server awhile to clean things up.  It's a pretty horrible failure.  Anyway, make 100% sure you have compatible versions of socket.io on client and server.  If you get the client version from `/socket.io/socket.io.js`, then it will always match your server.

Comment: I was indeed using an older client js from the cdn (1.4.5) for a while after updating socket.io locally to 2.x. Though that was 7 days ago, and I switched to using `/socket.io/socket.io.js` 5 days ago. I would think things would have cleaned up by now, but maybe that is indeed the issue? How would one go about manually clearing out all old client connections? I've searched for info on that with no luck.

Comment: If you have old clients that are maintaining their connection from an older version of the web page (that refers to the older version of socket.io) without refreshing their web page or ever navigating to a new page, I don't know what to do about that.

Comment: I ended up giving up and switched to Tornado and Sockjs. I've been fighting this dumb little socket.io app for years, wondering why it gobbled 100–300mb and ~100% CPU per instance, Tornado is now using 30mb and .3% CPU per instance. What a difference. Python ftw.